# Записать в базу измененные поля

Tags: php, javascript

Есть форма с заполненными полями (редактирования данных), я хочу записать в базу только те поля которые были изменены есть метод `.serializeArray()` который возвращает все данные, а как сделать чтобы он возвращал только те поля которые были изменены.

Пример кода:

```
var elements={};
$("#myform").change(function(){
    elements=$(this).serializeArray();
});
$("#myform").submit(function(){
    var order_id = $('#order_id').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/index.php?route=account/order/history_edit_order',
        data:{
            "action":elements,
            "order_id":order_id
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#test').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var elements = [], form = $("#myform");

form.on('change', event => {
  var name = event.target.name, value = event.target.value;
  elements = elements.filter(element => element.name !== name)
  elements.push({name, value});
  console.log(elements);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input name="input1" />
  <input name="input2" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать отфильтровать пустые поля, затем получить уже заполненные в виде массива:

```
//...........
$("#myform").change(function(){
    elements=$(this).find(input[type="text"]).filter(function () {
                return !!this.value;
             }).serializeArray();
});
//...........
```